# elasticsearch 5.6.1 : setting max shards that can be created in my any index in my cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am running an elasticsearch 5.6.1 cluster and wanted to know how I can restrict the max number of shards that an index can create. In Elasticsearch 1.7, I used this setting in the elasticsearch.yml which used to work :

```
index.number_of_shards: 1
```

IN 5.6.1, this seems to have changed and the above setting does not work.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: it works the same way in ES 5.6.1: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: Can you show the exact command you're running and the result?

Comment: I don't have control over indexing, so wanted to control this at the cluster/node level. The config file helped me achieve that in 1.7. I am looking for a way to achieve the same in 5.6

Answer (score 1):

need to use index templates for ES-5.6 version onwards. Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: Not sure this is what the OP is asking

Comment: Sorry if it was not very clear. I hope my comment to the question has made this clearer (I don't have control over indexing, so wanted to control this at the cluster/node level. The config file helped me achieve that in 1.7. I am looking for a way to achieve the same in 5.6 )

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ponni. Unfortunately, I don't have handle on the indexing. Is there a way I can control this at the node/cluster level ?